# styling Submenu CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, wordpress-theming

Im trying to style the submenu on my wordpress menu

http://www.milknhny.co.uk/SofiaWork/

I tried 
`.headermenu ul ul`

etc,... and it didnt work, can anyone suggest the correct class structure?

ive already  tried

`.headermenu ul li ul li` also

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your `ul`'s got an `id` attribute. Why not use it in css: 
`#menu-header-menu` - I think it is the top-level menu.
`#menu-header-menu .sub-menu` - targets ALL sub menus of top-level menu.

Comment: `#menu-header-menu.sub-menu` selects element with id `#menu-header-menu` that has class `.sub-menu`. Add a space: `#menu-header-menu .sub-menu`

Comment: ok i tried this but it didnt work :( #menu-header-menu .sub-menu ul li:hover {background-color: #5bb5e5;}

Comment: `.sub-menu` is already an `ul`. `#menu-header-menu .sub-menu li:hover`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to customise, but the anchor text also has a background which does not help styling, so if you remove this it can help you style the list item better.

```
#headermenu ul ul li a {
background: none;
}

#headermenu ul ul li a:hover, ul.headermenu ul ul li:hover {
background: none;
}
```

Then use :

```
#headermenu ul ul li {
background: red ;
}
```

AND:

```
#headermenu ul ul li:hover {
background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: I would take OFF the background for `.sub-menu li a` unless you want the anchor highlighted with a different colour. Then the above answers should help you style the list item.

`#headermenu ul ul li a,#headermenu ul ul li a:hover {
background: none;
}`